# Create Strictly Simple Polygon in PostGIS/Shapely

Tags: postgis, shapely, simplify

The clipper lib has an amazing function to create a strictly simple polygon (definition below).

Is it possible to do this in simple features (pref postgis or shapely)?

`A strictly simple polygon is a simple polygon that does not contain 'touching' vertices, or 'touching' edges.`

http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/Clipper/Properties/StrictlySimple.htm

Comment: What would be the input? If vertices touch, what should happen? Perhaps to get a multipolygon instead of non-simple polygon, or?

Comment: @user30184 yes one with holes prob

Comment: duplicate of [Stricly simple function-Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154418/stricly-simple-function-shapely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PostGIS use ST_MakeValid http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html

An example about self-touching ring:

[image]

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromText('
POLYGON (( 280 580, 400 580, 280 480, 400 480, 400 360, 280 360, 280 480, 280 580 ))')));
```

Result:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((280 480,400 480,400 360,280 360,280 480)),((280 580,400 580,280 480,280 580)))
```

Ring makes a hole

[image]

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromText('
POLYGON (( 280 580, 380 580, 380 500, 320 540, 320 460, 380 500, 380 440, 280 440, 280 580 ))')));
```

Result:

```
POLYGON((280 580,380 580,380 500,380 440,280 440,280 580),(380 500,320 540,320 460,380 500))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this not handle the touching edges case ?

Comment: Please provide test cases as WKT.

Comment: How would this be done in shapely? Thanks for the postgis result btw !